# How was the initial hash value (H(0)) of SHA-224 obtained?

Tags: hash, sha

[**RFC 6234**: US Secure Hash Algorithms (SHA and SHA-based HMAC and HKDF)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6234#section-6) explains only how the initial hash values (*H<sup>(0)</sup>*) for SHA-256, SHA-384, and SHA-512 were obtained. **How was the *H<sup>(0)</sup>* for SHA-224 obtained?**

> ### §6.1.  SHA-224 and SHA-256 Initialization
>
> For **SHA-224**, the initial hash value, H(0), consists of the following
> 32-bit words in hex:
>
> ```
> H(0)0 = c1059ed8
> H(0)1 = 367cd507
> H(0)2 = 3070dd17
> H(0)3 = f70e5939
> H(0)4 = ffc00b31
> H(0)5 = 68581511
> H(0)6 = 64f98fa7
> H(0)7 = befa4fa4
> ```
>
> For **SHA-256**, the initial hash value, H(0), consists of the following
> eight 32-bit words, in hex.  These words were obtained by taking **the
> first 32 bits of the fractional parts of the square roots of the
> first eight prime numbers**.
>
> ```
> H(0)0 = 6a09e667
> H(0)1 = bb67ae85
> H(0)2 = 3c6ef372
> H(0)3 = a54ff53a
> H(0)4 = 510e527f
> H(0)5 = 9b05688c
> H(0)6 = 1f83d9ab
> H(0)7 = 5be0cd19
> ```

> ### §6.3.  SHA-384 and SHA-512 Initialization
>
> For **SHA-384**, the initial hash value, H(0), consists of the
> following eight 64-bit words, in hex.  These words were obtained by
> taking **the first 64 bits of the fractional parts of the square
> roots of the ninth through sixteenth prime numbers**.
>
> ```
> H(0)0 = cbbb9d5dc1059ed8
> H(0)1 = 629a292a367cd507
> H(0)2 = 9159015a3070dd17
> H(0)3 = 152fecd8f70e5939
> H(0)4 = 67332667ffc00b31
> H(0)5 = 8eb44a8768581511
> H(0)6 = db0c2e0d64f98fa7
> H(0)7 = 47b5481dbefa4fa4
> ```
>
> For **SHA-512**, the initial hash value, H(0), consists of the
> following eight 64-bit words, in hex.  These words were obtained by
> taking **the first 64 bits of the fractional parts of the square
> roots of the first eight prime numbers**.
>
> ```
> H(0)0 = 6a09e667f3bcc908
> H(0)1 = bb67ae8584caa73b
> H(0)2 = 3c6ef372fe94f82b
> H(0)3 = a54ff53a5f1d36f1
> H(0)4 = 510e527fade682d1
> H(0)5 = 9b05688c2b3e6c1f
> H(0)6 = 1f83d9abfb41bd6b
> H(0)7 = 5be0cd19137e2179
> ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the first component of initial value of SHA-224:

```
H(0)0 = c1059ed8
```

This is the first component of the initial value of SHA-384

```
H(0)0 = cbbb9d5dc1059ed8
```

Notice that the last 32 bits of SHA-384 is exactly the value of SHA-224.

Comment: Oh, so then, they are **the second 32 bits of the fractional parts of the square roots of the ninth through sixteenth prime numbers**. I couldn't notice it. Thank you.